# Collision Resolution Linear Probing Java

Tags: java, linear-probing

So I am trying to detect for collisions in my linear method, which is hashing the keys of my hash map studentMap. I have the basic function for the linear probing, however I am struggling to detect if a key is already there (and therefore + 1). So far this code does not work - it does not check the key from my map studentMap as to whether it is there or not.
Any help much appreciated! I have removed some of the other hash methods to reduce the size of this code as they are irrelevant.

```
 public class Main  {
   Student student;
   public static boolean vartrue;
   HashMap next;
    public HashMap<String,Student> studentMap;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        HashMap<String, String> studentMap = new HashMap<>(16, 0.75f);
        //et keys and value
        studentMap.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
            String value = studentMap.get(key);
            System.out.println("Key = " + key + ", Value = " + value);
        });   
        //adding values to array
        studentMap.put("16012804", "Jennifer");
        studentMap.put("13747732", "Beatrice");
        studentMap.put("14056983", "Mavis");
        studentMap.put("16013464", "Geoffrey");
        studentMap.put("14058392", "Bob");
        studentMap.put("15405833", "Bill");
        studentMap.put("14058039", "Gertrude");
        studentMap.put("13056496", "Dorothy");
        //iterating through the array
        Set set = studentMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry mapentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            System.out.print("Key is: "+ mapentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
            System.out.println(mapentry.getValue());
        }
       //Get values based on key
        String var= studentMap.get("16012804");
        System.out.println("Value at index 1 is: "+var);
        // Remove values based on key
        studentMap.remove("16012804");
        System.out.println("Map key and values after removal:");
        Set set2 = studentMap.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
          Map.Entry mapentry2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
          System.out.print("Key is: "+mapentry2.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
          System.out.println(mapentry2.getValue());
        }
        Set keyset = studentMap.keySet();
        System.out.println("Key set values are:" + keyset);
        boolean val = studentMap.isEmpty();
        System.out.println("Is hash map empty: " + val);
        //get values
        Collection<String> values = studentMap.values();
        System.out.println("Map values = " + values);
        //size of table
        System.out.println("Size of the Hashtable: " + studentMap.size());
        //initial capacity
        System.out.println("Initial Capacity: " + 16);
        //capacity of map
        System.out.println("Map capacity: " +  mapcapacity(studentMap));
        //load factor
        System.out.println("Load Factor: " + loadFactor(studentMap));

        //linear probing
        System.out.println("...");
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Jennifer\")="+ linear(studentMap, "16012804"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Mavis\")="+ linear(studentMap, "14056983"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Geoffrey\")="+ linear(studentMap, "16013464"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Bill\")="+ linear(studentMap, "15405833"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Gertrude\")="+ linear(studentMap, "14058039"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Beatrice\")="+ linear(studentMap, "13747732"));
        System.out.println("Hash Value(\"Bob\")="+ linear(studentMap, "14058392"));

         if (vartrue = true)
             {
             Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>(mapcapacity(studentMap) * 2);
             map1.putAll(studentMap); 
             //capacity of the new hash map. (reflection)
             System.out.println("Map 1 mappings= " + map1);
             Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
             tableField.setAccessible(true);
             Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(map1);
             System.out.println("Size of Map 1: ");
             System.out.println(table == null ? 0 : table.length);
             }

        }
    //when to increase the hashmap size is calculated by capacity of hashmap divided by load factor:
    public static double loadFactor(Map studentMap){
    double count = studentMap.size();
        double load = count/mapcapacity(studentMap);
        return load;
    }
    //if the size of the map is greater than the map capacity * load factor - then double the size of map. 
    public static Integer mapcapacity(Map studentMap){
        //default capacity and load factor
       Integer initCapacity= 11;
       float loadFactor=0.75f;
       boolean capacityFound=false;
        Integer capacity=initCapacity;
        Integer size=studentMap.size();
        while(!capacityFound){
            if(size>capacity*loadFactor){
                //increase capacity 
                capacity=capacity * 2;  
                vartrue = true; 
            }
            else {
                capacityFound=true;   
            }
        }
        return capacity;
    }




    //linear probing
    public static int hashThis(String key, Map studentMap) {
        return key.hashCode()& 0x7fffffff % mapcapacity(studentMap); 
    }
    public static int linear(Map studentMap, String key){
    String value = studentMap.get(key).toString();
    int counter = 0;
    int hash = hashThis(key, studentMap);
    if (value != null)
    {
    hash = (hash + 1) % mapcapacity(studentMap);
    counter ++;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
     return hash;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you've decided to implement your own hash map manually, rather than using `java.util.HashMap` , which is already running in a linear probing manner.
In that case, the source of java.util.HashMap might be a big hint. From "grepcode.com" site, I found source codes of `put(K key, V value)` method of `java.util.HashMap` as follows;

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
     ... // null check on key : omitted

     int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);

     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
             ... // if the same key already exists, return the old value : omitted
         }
     }
     modCount++;
     addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
     return null;
}
```

Before `addEntry()` is called, `for` statement is iterated searching for an available space. (That is, when exiting `for` loop, `i` indicates an index for an available space for the new entry.) You may also check `get()`, the dual method of `put()`, for better understanding.

I think, the most important thing here for you is that `java.util.HashMap` does NOT seem to "change the hashcode" for linear probing. This is the main difference from your approach since `linear()` in your code seems to adjust the `hash` for a given `key`, everytime when the space for the hash value is already taken.

In addition, `linear()` in your code does not use iteration for searching a free space, but `mapcapacity()` does for size extention. This might cause mutiple space adjustment for a single key insertion, so does not seem like an efficient way for linear probling.

In summary, I'd like to suggest to check the source codes of of `java.util.HashMap` or related classes ;)